# Can't filter wp_get_attachment_link

Tags: functions, attachments, links, filters

Can't figure out why this won't work:

```
function my_get_attachment_link($html){
    $postid = get_the_ID();
    $html = str_replace('<a','<a rel="shadowbox['.$postid.']"',$html);
    return $html;
}
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_link','my_get_attachment_link',10,1);
```

Just trying to hook up all the images on a single post view to a lightbox script.

FYI, this didn't work either: http://wordpress.mfields.org/2010/thickbox-for-wordpress-gallery/#highlighter_196509

What could be jamming it up?

Comment: In what context are you calling `wp_get_attachment_link()`? A copy/paste of your code works with a call to `wp_get_attachment_link(36)` I randomly pasted into a template.

Comment: @milo: Hmmm, I thought this was getting called internally when the post page is constructed. Is that not the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code only works if you are actually *calling `wp_get_attachment_link()` somewhere in your template*. If you're not calling the function, then the `apply_filters()` *inside the function* will never get called, and therefore your code will have nothing into which to hook.